# Terraform: Error lookup: argument 1 should be type map, got type string in:

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform lookup() function is failing while parsing json. I am trying to get the values from a JSON file to a resource parameter. There are many parameters and I wanted to pass them from JSON file or a simple text file.

```
module main.tf
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "default" {
  count           = "${var.enabled == "true" ? length(var.parameter_write) : 0}"
  name            = "${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "name")}"
  description     = "${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "description", lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "name"))}"
  type            = "${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "type", "SecureString")}"
  value           = "${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "value")}"
  overwrite       = "${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "overwrite", "false")}"
  allowed_pattern = "${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "allowed_pattern", "")}"
  tags            = "${var.tags}"
}
```

root module main.tf

```
data "template_file" "env" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/env.tpl")}"
}

module "parameter-store" {
  source = "../../modules/ssm"

  parameter_write = ["${data.template_file.env.rendered}"]

  tags = {
    ManagedBy = "Terraform"
  }
}
```

template file

```
[
  {
    name      = "NAME_1"
    value     = "1440"
    type      = "String"
    overwrite = "true"
  },
  {
    name      = "NAME_2"
    value     = "100000"
    type      = "String"
    overwrite = "true"
  },
  {
    name        = "NAME_3"
    value       = "10080"
    type        = "String"
    overwrite   = "true"
    description = "example variable"
  },
]
```

Error:

```
module.parameter-store.aws_ssm_parameter.default: At column 3, line 1: lookup: argument 1 should be type map, got type string in:

${lookup(var.parameter_write[count.index], "value")}
```

What would be the ideal way to achieve this sort of use case?

Answer (score 1):

Are you defining the module variable parameter_write as a list? is so try this.

```
"${lookup(element(var.parameter_write, count.index), "value"}"
```

If this does not work, what version of terraform are you using? because it looks like the array value is returning a string instead of map. If that is so, you can

```
 data "external" "map" {
      program = ["echo", "${element(var.parameter_write, count.index)}"]
 }

   output "ssm_value" {
      value = "${data.external.map.value}"
   }
```